R-markdown to HTML: slider or zoom for wide plots (mimic zoom button in RStudio)
I have an Rmarkdown file that generates a html file with a lot of plots in different tabs. Some of the plots (in different tabs) have a lot of values on the x-axis (for categorical variables). When I plot these objects individually in RStudio, I can click on the zoom button in RStudio, and the window that pops up will adjust to the width of the plot somehow, so I can see all the values on the x-axis clearly. In my report, on the other hand, all the categorical values on the x-axis are crammed together. I need to fix this, either using a slider of some sort, or to be able to mimic the zoom button in RStudio.
I tried following the answer here:
Zoom function in rmarkdown html plot
, but it does not adjust the image. It just blows up an already blurry image / or an image with already crammed up x-axis values.
I have made a reproducible example below. When you knit the Rmarkdown file below, you will see that there are too many values in the report for the first variable. The x-axis is unreadable.
---
title: "Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float:
    collapsed: false
  toc_depth: 1
  number_sections: false
  theme: paper
params:
  list_obj: "A list of objects that are used in sections of the report"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
n_var=70
N=1000
dt<-data.table(var1=as.character(sample(1:n_var, replace=T,size=N)), 
               var2=sample(1:10, replace=T, size=N),
               response=rnorm(N),
               exposure=rgamma(N, 1))

list_obj <- list()
list_obj[['var1']] <- dt[, .(factor=mean(response),
                              exposure=sum(exposure)), by=var1][order(-var1)]
list_obj[['var2']] <- dt[, .(factor=mean(response),
                              exposure=sum(exposure)), by=var2][order(-var2)]

# plot function
my_plot_func <- function(data, var) {
  library(ggplot2)
  # extract information from token
  var_is_num <- ifelse(is.character(data[[var]]), F, T)

  if (!var_is_num) {
    p <- ggplot(data = data) + geom_point(aes(x=get(var), y=factor))
    
    e <- ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = var, y = "exposure")) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue2",
                 size = 0.8, alpha = .4) +
        labs(x = "", y = "exposure")  +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA))
      
      # this aligns horizontal scales of the two plots:
      p <- ggplotGrob(p)
      e <- ggplotGrob(e)
      max_width = grid::unit.pmax(p$widths[2:5], e$widths[2:5])
      p$widths[2:5] <- as.list(max_width)
      e$widths[2:5] <- as.list(max_width)
      p <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p, e, ncol = 1, heights = c(3,1))
    } else {
      p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = get(var), y = factor), 
                  alpha = 0.8)
        e <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = get(var), weight = exposure)) +
        geom_density(fill = "steelblue2", size = 0.8, alpha = .4) +
        labs(x = "") +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA))
      
      # this aligns horizontal scales of the two plots:
      p <- ggplotGrob(p)
      e <- ggplotGrob(e)
      max_width = grid::unit.pmax(p$widths[2:5], e$widths[2:5])
      p$widths[2:5] <- as.list(max_width)
      e$widths[2:5] <- as.list(max_width)
      p <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p, e, ncol = 1, heights = c(3,1))
    }
  return(p)
}

# function I use in rmarkdown report
tab_plots <- function(list_object) {
  for (var in names(list_object)) {
    cat("##", var, "{.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}\n\n")
    suppressWarnings(plot(my_plot_func(
      data = list_object[[var]],
      var = var
      )))
    cat("\n \n")
  }
}
```
  
# Inspect model {.tabset .tabset-fade}
  
```{r, out.width='100%', echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
tab_plots(list_obj)
```

-->

, but when I plot the first variable by itself in RStudio, I can press the zoom button and voila, I can read the x-axis:
plot(my_plot_func(list_obj[[1]], "var1"))

. Without zoom it comes off like in the html-file:


I have found a way using plotly, but it does not work with tabsets, does anybody know how I make that work?
---
title: "Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      toc_depth: 1
    number_sections: false
    theme: paper
params:
  list_obj: "A list of objects that are used in sections of the report"
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
n_var=70
N=1000
dt<-data.table(var1=as.character(sample(1:n_var, replace=T,size=N)), 
               var2=sample(1:10, replace=T, size=N),
               response=rnorm(N),
               exposure=rgamma(N, 1))

list_obj <- list()
list_obj[['var1']] <- dt[, .(factor=mean(response),
                             exposure=sum(exposure)), by=var1][order(-var1)]
list_obj[['var2']] <- dt[, .(factor=mean(response),
                             exposure=sum(exposure)), by=var2][order(-var2)]

# plot function
my_plot_func <- function(data, var) {
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)
  # extract information from token
  var_sym <- sym(var)
  var_is_num <- ifelse(is.character(data[[var]]), F, T)
  
  if (!var_is_num) {
    p <- ggplot(data=data) + geom_point(aes(x = !!var_sym, y = factor))
    
    e <- ggplot(data, aes(x = !!var_sym, y = exposure)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue2", alpha = 0.4) +
      labs(x = "", y = "exposure")

  } else {
    p <- ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x = !!var_sym, y = factor))
    
    e <- ggplot(data = data) +
      geom_density(aes(x = !!var_sym, weight = exposure), 
                   fill = "steelblue2", alpha = .4) +
      labs(x = "") +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA))
  }
  
  # Convert to plotly objects
  p_plotly <- ggplotly(p)
  e_plotly <- ggplotly(e)
  
  # Combine plots and share x-axis
  p <- subplot(p_plotly, e_plotly, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, heights = c(0.8, 0.2))
  # p <- plotly_build(p)
  return(p)
}

# function I use in rmarkdown report
tab_plots <- function(list_object) {
  for (var in names(list_object)) {
    cat("##", var, "{.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}\n\n")
    my_plot_func(data = list_object[[var]], var=var)
    cat("\n \n")
  }
}
```

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a');
  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      }, 200);
    });
  });
});
</script>

# Inspect model {.tabset .tabset-fade}

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
tab_plots(list_obj)
```

-->

